# How to scrape data using next button with ellipsis using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to continuously get the data on next button <1 2 3 ... 5> but there's no provided href link in the source also there's also elipsis. any idea please? here's my code

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = (
        (self.parse_2, 'https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale'),
    )
    for cb, url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=cb)


def parse_2(self, response):
    for product_item_forever in response.css('div.pi_container'):
        forever_item = {
            'forever-title': product_item_forever.css('p.p_name::text').extract_first(),
            'forever-regular-price': product_item_forever.css('span.p_old_price::text').extract_first(),
            'forever-sale-price': product_item_forever.css('span.p_sale.t_pink::text').extract_first(),
            'forever-photo-url': product_item_forever.css('img::attr(data-original)').extract_first(),
            'forever-description-url': product_item_forever.css('a.item_slider.product_link::attr(href)').extract_first(),
        }
        yield forever_item
```

Please help me thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems this pagination uses additional request to API. 
So, there are two ways:

1. Use Splash/Selenium to render pages by pattern of QHarr;
2. Make same calls to API. Check developer tools, you will find POST-request `https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/Catalog/GetProducts` will all proper params (they are too long, so I will not post full list here).

Comment: Hi @vezunchik thank you for helping me but I am so sorry I don't know understand about make same calls to API?

Comment: This is quite time-taking, you should really try it by yourself. Check developer tools, get curl, detect all needed fields, headers, maybe cookies and then set them to Request.

Comment: Really thankful on your help @vezunchik, I've tried what you had told me and I really don't get the idea. this is really frustrating as I am really new on this language.

Answer (score 1):

The url changes so you can specify page number and results per page in the url e.g.

```
https://www.forever21.com/uk/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale/#pageno=2&pageSize=120&filter=price:0,250
```

As mentioned by @vezunchik and OP feedback, this approach requires selenium/splash to allow js to run on the page.  If you were going down that route you could just click the next ( `.p_next`)  until you get the end page as it is easy to grab the last page number (`.dot + .pageno`)from the document.

---

I appreciate you are trying with scrapy.

Demo of the idea with selenium in case helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url_loop = 'https://www.forever21.com/uk/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale/#pageno={}&pageSize=120&filter=price:0,250'
url = 'https://www.forever21.com/uk/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)

d.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick="fnAcceptCookieUse()"]').click() #get rid of cookies
items =  WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#products .p_item")))
d.find_element_by_css_selector('.selectedpagesize').click()
d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.pagesize')[-1].click() #set page result count to 120
last_page = int(d.find_element_by_css_selector('.dot + .pageno').text) #get last page

if last_page > 1:
    for page in range(2, last_page + 1):
        url = url_loop.format(page)
        d.get(url)
        try:
            d.find_element_by_css_selector('[type=reset]').click() #reject offer
        except:
            pass
        # do something with page
        break #delete later
```

Comment: Hi @Qharr thank you for answering, I tried that part but it's not working, if you will try to change the pageno, like for example pageno=2 it will just automatically go back to pageno=1

Comment: Haven't tested but if you browser automate the url appears to take you to the right page and stay there. But that said, if you were going down that route you could just click the next until you get the end page as it is easy to grab the last page number from the document if javascript is allowed to run.

Comment: But still even I tried to change the url it never runs, unless I click the specific pagination next button which is the number <1 2 3 ... 5 >

Comment: Is that with selenium?

Comment: hi @Qharr! I really appreciated your effort helping me to solve my problem, but unfortunately I am using SHub and needs to be Scrapy, any possible way on solving this? Thank you so much