# How to use one bot for different websites

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape 2 different website. One of them is plain html and the other one  javascript (for which I need splash to scrape it).
So I have several questions about it:

1. Can I scrape two different types of websites with only one bot (html and javascript one)? I did two html websites before and it worked but I wonder if this also works if one of them is javascript
2. If the first question is possible can I export json separately? Like for url1 output1.json, for url2 output2.json?
3. As you can see from my code, code need edited and I dont know how can I do that when two different types of websites need to be scraped.
4. Is there any tool of scrapy to compare json? (The two different websites have almost the same content. I want make output1.json the base and check if some value are different in output2.json or not.

My code:

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'mybot'
    allowed_domains = ['url1','url2']


    def start_requests(self):
        urls = (
            (self.parse1, 'url1'),
            (self.parse2, 'url2'),
        )
        for callbackfunc, url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=callbackfunc)
            #In fact url2 must for javascript website so I need clearly splash here
    def parse1(self, response):
        pass

    def parse2(self,response):
        pass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scrape data using next button with ellipsis using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593755/how-to-scrape-data-using-next-button-with-ellipsis-using-scrapy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can scrape more than one site with the same spider, but it doesn't make sense if they are too different. The way to do that you have already figured out: `allowed_domains` and `start_requests` (or `start_urls`). However, exporting to different files won't be straightforward. You will have to write your export code.

IMHO having one spider per site is the way to go. If they share some code, you can have a `BaseSpider` class from where your spiders can inherit.

And regarding the javascript site you mentioned, are you sure you can not request its API directly?